# Website Scraping with BeautifulSoup : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am an absolute beginner. I try to use BeautifulSoup and scrape a website. I do get the HTML, but I would like to now get all the `divs` that have the class `content_class`.

Here is my attempt:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

#Request the page and parse the HTML
url = 'mywebsite'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

#Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.find_all('div', class_="content_class")
```

This does not work however.
I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "scrape.py", line 11, in
>   
>       soup.find_all('div', class_="content_class") TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you put `print(soup.find_all)` on the second-to-last line, what is printed?

Comment: So I did `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)` and then 
`print(soup.find_all)` and what is printed is `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using BeautifulSoup [version *three*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html), but appear to be following the documentation for BeautifulSoup [version four](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The [`Element.find_all()` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) is only available in latest major version (it is called [`Element.findAll()` in version 3](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Searching%20the%20Parse%20Tree)).

I strongly urge you to upgrade:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Version 3 has stopped receiving updates in 2012; it is severely out of date now.

Comment: thanks, I did that! However, I now get `The code that caused this warning is on line 10 of the file scrape.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html.parser")

  markup_type=markup_type))`

Comment: @GeorgeWelder, just follow the instructions in the warning. You also may simply ignore it.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder: yes, BeautifulSoup 4 used to auto-select a parsing backend for you, but that'd led to unexpected changes when you then installed LXML later on. You now are asked to make an explicit choice: `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')` or `soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')`.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder: see [*installing a parser*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for the pros and cons of each choice.

Comment: Thanks. I did that, and I will look into it more! However, although I don't get any more errors, I now get back an empty array (although theres nothing wrong with the HTML document and I'm sure that there are multiple divs with  `content_class`)

Comment: @george You should accept an answer as the problem you're describing is different from the original question you asked. If you can't make it work, you should then consider asking a new question.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder: that'd be a *separate issue* from the question you posted. It could be that you are served broken HTML, or that the specific HTML elements you are trying to find are actually *not part of the source document* but are generated by JavaScript code run by your browser. `BeautifulSoup` is not a browser and can't execute JavaScript code.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because there is no method "find_all" in BeautifulSoup, there is "findAll" method, this code should help

```
 soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'content_class'})
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and the error is gone, but I get an empty array: `[]`, but I am sure that the class `content_class` exists in the document in multiple divs.

Comment: You really should not be using BeautifulSoup version 3 anymore. It has been unmaintained for over 5 years now.